# AWS DynamoDb DocumentClient - Creating a batchWrite from an array of Items - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to perform a `batchWrite` operation using DynamoDB's `DocumentClient` from an array of items (JSON)

This is my code:

```
var items = [];

for (i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    var ord = orders[i]; //a simple json object
    var item = { 
        'PutRequest': { 
            'Item' : ord[i] 
        } 
    };

    items.push(item);
 }


var params = {
    RequestItems: {
        'my_table_name': items
    }
};

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('There was a problem putting the items in the table');
        context.fail(err);
    } 
    else {
        console.log('Items updated in table');
        context.done();
    }
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{"errorMessage":"Missing required key 'Item' in        
 params.RequestItems['my_table_name']
 [0].PutRequest","errorType":"MissingRequiredParameter"...
```

I have looked at the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#batchWrite-property) but I can't understand what I 
am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you also getting the console log : `console.log('There was a problem putting the items in the table');`?  At what point is this error being printed out?  What's the content of your params before the `batchWrite`?

Comment: No I have figured it out. Will add answer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
function batchWrite(arrayOf25) {

 //25 is as many as you can write in one time

  var itemsArray = [];

  for (i = 0; i < arrayOf25.length; i++) {

    var someItem = arrayOf25[i];
    var item = {
                PutRequest: {
                 Item: someItem
                }
             };


    if (item) {
      itemsArray.push(item);
    }

 }


  var params = {
      RequestItems: { 
        'my_table_name': itemsArray
      }
    };

    //var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); //These should be added at the top
    //var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

    docClient.batchWrite(params, function(err, data) {

      if (err) {
          console.log(err); 
      } 
      else  {

          console.log('Added ' + itemsArray.length + ' items to DynamoDB');

      }   


    });


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct way to do it using the Javascript SDK v3. There is nothing wrong with the original answer, but it is seven years later.

I want to highlight the following:

- the use of `slice` to generate chunks of 25 records
- the use of parallelism to send all write requests in parallel so that you can write 1000 records in tens of milliseconds or less, depending on network bandwidth.

You'll need to change the table name and write the item mapping function to map your data. Retry is included in case of failure, but it is not robust enough for a production scenario, you will probably need a fallback mechanism such as DLQ.

```js
import {
    BatchWriteItemCommand, BatchWriteItemCommandOutput, BatchWriteItemOutput,
    DynamoDBClient, WriteRequest
} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
```

```js
async function writeRecordsToDynamoDb(records: DynamoDbData[]): Promise<void> {
    const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({region: process.env.AWS_REGION});
    const tableName = process.env.DATA_TABLE;
    const writeRequests: WriteRequest[] = records.map(record => ({
        PutRequest: {
            Item: {
                ts: {S: record.timestamp},
                id: {S: record.flowId},
                v: {N: record.flow.toString()}
            }
        }
    }));
    await processWriteRequests(ddbClient, tableName, writeRequests);
    console.log(`Wrote ${records.length} records to DynamoDB`);
}

async function processWriteRequests(ddbClient: DynamoDBClient,
                                    tableName: string,
                                    writeRequests: WriteRequest[],
                                    retryCount = 0) {
    if (retryCount > DDB_MAX_RETRIES) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to write ${writeRequests.length} records to DynamoDB after 3 retries`);
        //TODO: should have some fallback mechanism here, such as DLQ
    }
    const promises: Promise<BatchWriteItemCommandOutput>[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < writeRequests.length; i += DDB_BATCH_SIZE) {
        const requestItems: Record<string, WriteRequest[]> = {};
        requestItems[tableName] = writeRequests.slice(i, i + DDB_BATCH_SIZE);
        const command = new BatchWriteItemCommand({
            RequestItems: requestItems
        });
        promises.push(ddbClient.send(command));
    }
    const results: BatchWriteItemOutput[] = await Promise.all(promises);
    const unprocessedItems: WriteRequest[] = [];
    for (const result of results) {
        if (result.UnprocessedItems && result.UnprocessedItems[tableName]) {
            unprocessedItems.push(...result.UnprocessedItems[tableName]);
        }
    }
    if (unprocessedItems.length > 0) {
        console.log(`Retrying ${unprocessedItems.length} unprocessed items`);
        await processWriteRequests(ddbClient, tableName, unprocessedItems, retryCount + 1);
    }
}
```

dependencies

```bash
npm install -s @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb @aws-sdk/types
```